# How to display an image and a terminal in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

How can use OpenCV to display my webcam and a terminal at the same time? I need the terminal to run some commands to make the webcam appear and others different actions with the object detection.

Comment: you need a GUI? with tkinter, qt, gtk, ...?

Comment: yes but I would like to make like a console GUI

Comment: can you mock up a picture of what you mean?

Comment: you need something to call `waitkey` periodically so the default gui can update (after calling `imshow` or something). This can be done from a separate thread while the main process can use the normal python `input` (`raw_input` for py 2.x) on the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple example of running a webcam while at the same time being able to use terminal `input()` by doing all the opencv frame capturing, and `imshow`ing from a separate thread:

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2

shouldExit = False
color = True

def cam():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    while not shouldExit:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not color:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow("window title", frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

t = Thread(target=cam)
t.start()

while True:
    print('select an action: q-quit, t-toggle color')
    choice = input(">").strip().lower()
    if choice == 'q':
        shouldExit = True
        t.join()
        break
    elif choice == 't':
        color = not color
    else:
        print('invalid input')
```

Comment: `cv2.CAP_DSHOW` What is this?

Comment: @Tudor it's not strictly necessary in all cases, but it tells opencv [what api to prefer](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294da77ab1fe260fd182f8ec7655fab27a31d). In my case there was a warning that the camera was not closed correctly when using auto detect (not specifying an api)

Comment: you can often safely omit that argument, and simply call `cv2.VideoCapture(0)`. It is equivalent to `cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_ANY)`.